# Multidimenssional Array Loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have Array that look like this:

```
array('2014' => array('My','Name','Is','A'), 
      '2015' => array('My','Name','Is','B'),
      '2016' => array('My','Name','Is','C')
     )
```

Question : how can i loop only the year (2014,2015,206) with PHP foreach function ?

i want result like this:
2014, 2015, 2016

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $years= [];
 foreach($yourArray as $key => $val)
 {
    $years[] = $key;
 }
 echo implode(',',$years);
```

Your years is your `key`

Answer (score 3):

`array_keys` & `implode` will help. You can try this -

```
echo implode(',', array_keys($your_array));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
$arr = array('2014' => array('My','Name','Is','A'), 
      '2015' => array('My','Name','Is','B'),
      '2016' => array('My','Name','Is','C')
     )

$yearArr = array();

foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
     $yearArr[] = $key;
}

echo implode(",",$yearArr);
```